# Why Generic Casting is not working on this section of code?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
IQueryable<T> IS3Repository.FindAllBuckets<T>()
{
  IQueryable<object> list = _repository.GetAllBuckets().Cast<object>().AsQueryable();
  return list == null ? default(T) : (T)list;
}
```

This is the error:
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am implementing this interface:

```
 IQueryable<T> FindAllBuckets<T>();
```

What is the problem?

This is what I have tried:

1. ```
   IQueryable<T> IS3Repository.FindAllBuckets<T>()
   {
       IQueryable<object> list = _repository
                                 .GetAllBuckets()
                                 .Cast<object>().AsQueryable();

       return list == null ? list.DefaultIfEmpty().AsQueryable() : list; }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting `list` to `T` but the return value of `FindAllBuckets` is of type `IQueryable<T>`.

Depending on the return type of `_repository.GetAllBuckets()`, this should work:

```
IQueryable<T> IS3Repository.FindAllBuckets<T>()
{
    return _repository.GetAllBuckets()
                      .Cast<T>()
                      .AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IQueryable<T> IS3Repository.FindAllBuckets<T>()
{
    IQueryable<T> list = _repository
                         .GetAllBuckets()
                         .Cast<T>()
                         .AsQueryable();

    return list ?? new List<T>().AsQueryable();
}
```

The main problem with your original approach is that you were trying to return an instance of `T` rather than an instance of `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<object>' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>.  That is the error I got trying that.  Thanks.